# How the number of nodes are determined in random forest in R

Tags: r, random, nodes

I use `randomForest` package to perform a binary classification. I would like to ask how `randomForest()` determines the number of node in each tree? I think the number of node is saved in model$forest$nrnodes. Am I correct here?

In my dataset, I have 10,000 positive and 70,000 negative samples. I build several models with default parameters except for the number of trees 50,100,200 and 500. Their performance are quite similar. The number of nodes of each model is also quite similar, around 1400.

Could some explain how this 1400 is computed? Which parameter is used to control the number of nodes in each tree? Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: for classification, `randomForest` builds trees completely until there are 5 observations in every node. It then takes the majority class as the prediction.

Comment: The total number of nodes will depend on how many times `randomForest` split when building the tree.  As @Zelazny7 mentioned, each "leaf" will end up having 5 observations.

Comment: As for the parameter that controls the number of nodes, it depends on two parameters, `maxnodes` and `ntree`

Comment: @Zelazny7 I understand`maxnode` define the upper-bound of the tree size, and wont effect the size if the tree is not that "big". I do not understand how `ntree` play a role in controlling the tree size here.

Answer (score 1):

```
randomForest(x, y=NULL,  xtest=NULL, ytest=NULL, ntree=500,
         mtry=if (!is.null(y) && !is.factor(y))
         max(floor(ncol(x)/3), 1) else floor(sqrt(ncol(x))),
         replace=TRUE, classwt=NULL, cutoff, strata,
         sampsize = if (replace) nrow(x) else ceiling(.632*nrow(x)),
         nodesize = if (!is.null(y) && !is.factor(y)) 5 else 1,
         maxnodes = NULL,
         importance=FALSE, localImp=FALSE, nPerm=1,
         proximity, oob.prox=proximity,
         norm.votes=TRUE, do.trace=FALSE,
         keep.forest=!is.null(y) && is.null(xtest), corr.bias=FALSE,
         keep.inbag=FALSE, ...)
```

In nodesize, the `TRUE` condition for that `if` statement is if `y` exists and is not a factor, or a categorical variable used for classification. Therefore the `FALSE` condition is `nodesize=1`. So it will keep splitting on your predictor variables until each node is pure, regardless of number of number of trees. They will be slightly different because of the randomness when building the trees.